# Linux загрузчик системы

Tags: linux

В linux ни че не смыслю. Установил Linux Ubuntu, в конце он написал что не получилось установить толи загрузчик системы то ли  че то подобное. При включении компа пишет "error: file not found" и "grub rescue>". Объясните пожалуйста доступным образом что делать

Answer (score 2):

Плохо установился загрузчик, попробуйте тут - [восстановление GRUB](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_grub) - почитать.